Update updated_by and updated_date on soft delete in Hibernate
I implemented soft delete using @SQLDelete(sql="UPDATE table_name SET deleted = true WHERE id = ?") and it works fine. But how to update 'updated_by' and 'updated_date'. I can update 'updated_date' by inserting for example updated_date = now() into above query but how to update 'updated_by' for which I need user id that i get using SecurityContextHolder.
I try to use @PreRemove event but even though entity is updated the changes are not persisted.

Using @PreRemove won't directly work with @SQLDelete.
@PreRemove is triggered before the Hibernate session is flushed, but when using @SQLDelete, the custom SQL is executed directly, bypassing any changes that might have been made to the entity within the @PreRemove method.
Try using a custom repository method to handle the soft delete scenario. As mentioned below.
 @Transactional
    public void softDelete(Long entityId) {
        String username = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
    YourEntity entity = repository.findById(entityId)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Entity not found with id: " + entityId));

    entity.setDeleted(true);
    entity.setUpdatedBy(username);
    entity.setUpdatedDate(LocalDateTime.now());

    repository.save(entity);
}


Thanks for the answer, that's what I ended up doing. I was hoping I could achieve that with @SQLDelete because then I can define and use a cascading delete which could also  be soft. In this case I had to manually handle soft delete of the associated entities.
